# ERROR OMP change the value of an array outside the parallel part?

Tags: c, openmp

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>

void print_board(int* board, int board_size)
{
    for (int i =0; i<board_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j<board_size; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", board[i*board_size+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int size = 8;

    int *board = malloc(sizeof(int)*size*size);
    memset(board, 0, size*size);

    print_board(board, size);

    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        printf("Hello world from %d of %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The value of board is set to zero by memset which is outside of omp parallel block.
the value of board are not zeros as expected, is anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the argument to `malloc` then look at the last argument to `memset`. See any difference?

Comment: fwiw, `calloc()` is what you want to use here, it combines both `malloc()` and `memset(...,0,...)`